# manipulação de cookies

Tags: cookies

Bom dia Pessoal,

Estou com um site de uma empresa, e minha tarefa é fazer o translate. Foi solicitado que fosse em javascript e assim foi feito. Dessa forma, quando clico na bandeira, e seleciono o idioma, a página é traduzida. Porém, quando troco de página, vou para a ala "consumidor" por exemplo, o site não consegue manter o cookie do idioma, e volta para o padrão que é portugues.
Alguem pode me ajudar a resolver isso, por favor? Sugestões?

Segue link para analises:

http://whatsac.com/traducao/

Comment: você já tentou fazer uma verificação assim que a página abre, ou seja, se já existe um cookie com o nome xxxxxIdioma - ler o mesmo e aplicá-lo. seria um script padrão para ler cookies e existindo executa, do contrário é criado somente ao selecionar a bandeira. Se possível poste seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Meu script:

```
var _t = $('body').translate({lang: "pt", t: t});
    var str = _t.g("translate");
      console.log(str);

  $(".lang_selector").click(function(ev) {
    var lang = $(this).attr("data-value");
    _t.lang(lang);

    console.log(lang);
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Segue o header do meu html:

```
<header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
                <section id="location">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseNavbar" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#025b93;">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div id="lang_sel_list" class="lang_sel_list_horizontal">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="icl-br"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector active" data-value="pt" href="#" data-trn-key="translate to English"><img class="iclflag" src="images/br.png" height="12" alt="br" width="18">Brasil</a></li>
                                        <li class="icl-ar"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector" data-value="dk" href="#"><img class="iclflag" src="images/dk.png" height="12" alt="us" width="18">Dinamarca</a></li>
                                        <li class="icl-ar"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector" data-value="en" href="#"><img class="iclflag" src="images/us.png" height="12" alt="us" width="18">Global</a></li>
                                        <li class="icl-bo"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector" data-value="es" href="#"><img class="iclflag" src="images/es.png" height="12" alt="bo" width="18">España</a></li>
                                        <li class="icl-th"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector" data-value="fr" href="#"><img class="iclflag" src="images/fr.png" height="12" alt="th" width="18">France</a></li>
                                        <li class="icl-th"><a class="lang_sel_other lang_selector" data-value="it" href="#"><img class="iclflag" src="images/italia.png" height="12" alt="th" width="18">Italia</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="menuCentro">
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-responsive" width="190" height="57" style="float:left;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn ativo" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn" href="consumidor.html">CONSUMIDOR</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn" href="Empresa.html">EMPRESAS</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn" href="Parceiros.html">PARCEIROS</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn" href="QuemUsa.html">EXEMPLOS DE USO</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll trn" href="Contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
                                        <a id="btn-toggle-location" class="btn navbar-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNavbar">
                                            <span><img src="images/br.png" height="12" alt="br" width="18"></span><i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="traduc"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

E o arquivo translate ficaria assim:

```
$(function() {

    //header

     var t = {
    "HOME": {
      pt: "HOME"
    },
      "CONSUMIDOR": {
        pt: "CONSUMIDOR",
        en: "CONSUMER",
        es: "CONSUMIDOR",
        fr: "CONSOMMATEUR",
        it: "CONSUMATORI",
        dk: "FORBRUGER"
      },
```